# efficient alternative to fmod(x,2)

Tags: c, math

is there a more efficient way to perform:

```
f = fmod(x+1, 2)
```

to ascertain whether a value is even?

e.g.

`f = 1` for all even values of `x`

`f = 0` for all odd values of `x`

I only need this to work for the set of positive integers (my `x` datatype is `int`)

Comment: You can use the normal modulus operator with ints. I doubt it's any more efficient after optimizations, but `x&1` works as well.

Comment: wierdly the original fmod seems to be quicker then x%2 on analysis with gprof

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you using `fmod()` for an integer?

The standard test would be:

```
const int f = (x + 1) % 2; /* Will be 1 if x is even, 0 if it's odd. */
```

this uses the built-in integer modulo operator `%` to do the testing.

The addition of 1 is (in my opinion) a bit confusing, I'd do it as:

```
const int f = (x % 2) == 0;
```

Folks who "think in bits" often write the test as:

```
const int f = (x & 1) == 0;
```

since the least-significant bit must be clear for an integer to be even. That can be argued to be less clear, though.

Comment: i don't know - i'm reading someone elses code and trying to improve it. Would you perceive a performance difference between the two operators?

Comment: The least significant bit of an integer does not need to be clear for an integer to be even. Generally, one should use arithmetic operators (such as `%`) to operate on numeric values and bitwise operators (such as `&`) to operate on bits. That avoids errors like this (thinking that the bit representations of all integers are two’s complement). Also `x % 2 == 0` avoids overflow, unlike `(x+1) % 2`.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming positive integers

```
f = 1 - (x&1);
```

should work for you.

Comment: This challenges the [precedence rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence); the bitwise and binds less tightly than binary minus, so this is parsed as `f = (1 - x) & 1`. Not sure if that's a problem though, but I must say I find it a complicated solution, and the formatting makes it even more scary. :)

Comment: Thanks. I think it still works but it certainly wasn't what I'd intended.  Now updated.

Answer (score 1):

You could just cast to int, I suppose...

```
f = (int)x % 2;
```